# What cause frequency change of the acoustic signal (3 kHz to 10 kHz)?

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, audio, sound, acoustics

I am working on Acoustic Resonace testing in which I excite the sample and then record the sound (3 kHz to 10 kHz) by microphones. I do few times repetation of the same measurement in series (one after other) in which amplitude remains same in all the measurements but **frequency is changing by 0.5 to 5 Hz** even though threre is no change in the set-up and measurement conditions. Doppler shift is calculated but it is very small. I do not know the reason. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "frequency is changing". What frequency? How exactly do you excite? Can you share some plots of your data so we have a chance to understand what is going on?

Comment: Maybe you could check if the AC line in your setup is causing the frequency change, and then you could shield it accordingly.( I dont have enough points to comment yet)

Comment: Hello! frequency is changing means for example, if I excite the sample to vibrate with its eigen modes and record the acoustic signal by microphones and calculate the FFT using MATLAB in which if the first eigen peak is 1000 Hz then if I reapet the same measurement without changing any measurement conditions but still it cahnges or shifts to 1002 Hz. It means peak is changing by 2 Hz. I hope you get it.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer and time but can you please explain me how AC line can be reason for the chaning in the frequency? can it affect on the microphones?  Thanks

Comment: I faced a problem where because my setup was not properly grounded, the frequency components closer to the ac line and its harmonics were producing a beating effect because of the 60Hz signal and this was solved by separating the ADC from the main equipment. I am not sure if you are facing the same problem. Sorry if this doesnt answer your question

Comment: Hey Jatin, welcome to SE. Maybe you should provide some more info on your experiment. A frequency "shift" (change could be a better term) of 0.5 Hz or 2 Hz may be insignificant for some experiments or extremely significant for others. From my experience, frequency deviations of some small percentage is always to be expected in real systems (from measurement to measurement). In addition to that, maybe you should also specify the analysis parameters you use.